# Starting Activity when video is finished playing

Tags: android, android-activity, static, android-intent, android-videoview

In my Android app, I am trying to simply go back to my main Activity once a video that I am playing ends.  I have tried many workarounds, but I can't find a way to call StartActivity from the video onCompletionListener - I am getting the "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity" error.

I tried getting a context from the Activity that preceded the videoView, and passing that to the intent/startActivity.  That allowed the app to compile, but then I got a runtime exception.

Here is the code as it stands now, which gets the "cannot make a static reference" error - any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Videoscreen extends Activity{

public static VideoView myVideoView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);
    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.main_videoview);
    System.out.println("playing video oncreate");
    playVideo();
}
public static void playVideo(){

    // video finish listener
    myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(Videoscreen.this, Game.class);
            Videoscreen.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 

    String low_word = SpellingView.get_low_word();
    Uri bubblesUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.lalloinc.ilovetrucks/raw/"+ low_word + "_vid");
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(bubblesUri);
    myVideoView.start();

}
```

}

Comment: thanks so much for the code - I am going to try as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

If you know the time of the video then you try:

```
String uri1 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.race3;
        vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri1)); 
        vd.start();

new Thread() {
             public void run() {
                     try{

                             sleep(50000);
                     } catch (Exception e) {

                     }
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Video.this, Another.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   finish();
             }
     }.start();
```

if you don't know the time then you get the time as:

```
int vtime = vd.getDuration();
```

And then at thread sleep you just put this integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you started the Video Activity from the Activity you would like to go back to later, just calling finish() at the end of the video will do the job.

Starting the main Activity again creates a not necessarily wanted stack of activities.