# Detect when videoview stops playing

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have this code for playing a video on a `VideoView`

```
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
```

When video is finish playing I get message :" Sorry, this video can't be played". I want to cache the moment when video is finish playing. How can I do this?

Here is my code :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        path = extras.getString("path");
        idPlaylist = extras.getString("idPlaylist");
        timer = extras.getString("timer");

        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();

        myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        com.PlayerOrange.ViewPlaylist.class);
                i.putExtra("id", idPlaylist);
                i.putExtra("timer", timer);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();           
                }
          });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Playing "+myVideoView.isPlaying());
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (myVideoView.isPlaying()==true)) {
                //nothing happens
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    com.PlayerOrange.ViewPlaylist.class);
            i.putExtra("id", idPlaylist);
            i.putExtra("timer", timer);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question. I want that when backbutton is pressed and video is playing nothing to happens but it is not working too.

Comment: what is currentActivityName ?

Comment: I get the same message and VideoView is not static .

Comment: Visit the link I added in my answer. I tried your code an d its work fine in my case..

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried?

```
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    com.PlayerOrange.ViewPlaylist.class);
            i.putExtra("id", idPlaylist);
            i.putExtra("timer", timer);
            startActivity(i);
            currentActivityName.finish();           
    }
});
```

Also make sure your myVideoView not to have as static. If yes, then remove static..

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29)

Look at [Starting Activity when video is finished playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315279/starting-activity-when-video-is-finished-playing)

[Android – Video/Music player sample](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/)

[Playing Video](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/playingVideo.html)

[OnCompletion video notification on MediaController and VideView usage?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/82bae0bbcee85fb4)

[Android - Listener (or handler) for video finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847818/android-listener-or-handler-for-video-finish)

Comment: it's not working, I still get the message "Sorry, this video cannot be played"...and now if I press volume key the code from onCompletion is called :(

Comment: how can you remove static?